# Provide ?persitent? proxy auth credentials from extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension which provides a list of proxys to choose from and the user can set which one he likes. This is done via the following code:

```
var proxyConfig = {
    mode : "fixed_servers", 
    rules : {
        proxyForHttps : {
            scheme: "http",
            host: undefined,
            port: undefined
        },
        proxyForHttp : {
            scheme: "http",
            host: undefined,
            port: undefined
        },
        proxyForFtp : {
            host: undefined,
            port: undefined
        }
    }
};

function setProxyConfig (ip, port) {
    // sets ip and port for the various protocols

    proxyConfig.rules.proxyForHttps.host = ip;
    proxyConfig.rules.proxyForHttps.port = port;
    proxyConfig.rules.proxyForHttp.host = ip;
    proxyConfig.rules.proxyForHttp.port = port;
    proxyConfig.rules.proxyForFtp.host = ip;
    proxyConfig.rules.proxyForFtp.port = port;
};

setProxyConfig(ip, port);

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value : proxyConfig, scope : 'regular'}, function() {});
```

Now this proxy setting is **persistent**. If you restart Chrome it's still active. And that's where I run into a problem: The proxy authentication. Currently this is done via the following code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    function(details, callbackFn) {
        callbackFn({
            authCredentials: {
                username: String(Model.Options.username),
                password: String(Model.Options.passwordPlain)
            }
        });
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ['asyncBlocking']
);
```

My Problem now is, some users configured Chrome in a fashion where the last open tabs are re-opened on startup. Now instead of their tabs loading they get the chrome popup window which asks them to enter a username and password for the currently active proxy. This is a problem because we want to do this automatically via our extension. Ideally the user doesn't see the popup at all - which is the case except when she restarts Chrome and the tabs reopen again.

So it seems that the extension is loaded *after* these tabs are already requesting URLs - because the chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired listener isn't called for these tabs.

So the question is:
**Is there a way to make the username and password also persistent?**
How would you handle this?

Maybe it's a bug the extension is loaded after the tabs? Or can we make the listener persistent too?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Not an real solution (rather a workaround): As soon as your extension is loaded authenticate the user (make a request if necessary) and then reload all tabs.